# Flatbuffers how to send in one message uint16_t header, size_t body size and uint8_t buffer

Tags: c++, boost-asio, flatbuffers

I am using [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/index.html) & [Boost ASIO](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

I want to form a message with the following sequence:

1. uint16_t Header identifier. (fixed size message)
2. size_t body size <- so the reading part can know how long is the message that it needs to read. (fixed size message)
3. Flatbuffers object. (dynamic size message, size of which is sent at 2)

So for the first two here is how I combine them to be sent:

```
size_t const header_length = 8;
size_t const body_size_b = 8;

ServerOpcode opc;
opc = ServerOpcode::SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE_TEST;
std::string header = std::to_string(opc);
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
auto name = builder.CreateString("Orc MONSTER");
auto accountRole = Vibranium::CreateAccountRole_Packet(builder,1,name);
builder.Finish(accountRole);
size_t size = builder.GetSize();
uint8_t *buf = builder.GetBufferPointer();

std::array<char, header_length + body_size_b> buffer{};
std::copy(header.begin(), header.end(), buffer.begin());
std::copy(std::to_string(size).begin(), std::to_string(size).end(), buffer.begin() + header_length);
// How can I add builder here at third place ?
boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(buffer,sizeof(buffer)));
```

I don't know how to append the flatbuffers buffer after the first two.

My question is:

How can I unify all three in sequence and send them in one `boost::asio::write` ?

Comment: You are wasting your time, you have to learn before trying to go directly to "flat buffer", I bet that after understanding asio you will discover that you don't need flat buffer...

Comment: @JeanDavy how come? Boost Asio is library providing networking solution on the other side FlatBuffers provides convenient way for serialization/deserialization of the messages. How come Boost Asio makes FlatBuffers unnecessary ?

Comment: "How come Boost Asio ..." this is exactly why you have to learn asio !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 1) and 2). To get 1), declare a `file_identifier` in your schema, then pass that identifier to `Finish`. To get a 2) use `FinishSizePrefixed`. All this is in the docs that you're still not wanting to read.

And again, this is a binary format, so I am not sure what you're doing with `std::to_string` but it is not going to work. You just need to write the contents of `buf`. I have no idea how to use it with Boost.

Comment: Also I understand that I can set file identifier like this `auto accountRole = Vibranium::CreateAccountRole_Packet(builder,1,name);const char *HEADER = "ABCD";
  builder.FinishSizePrefixed(accountRole, HEADER);` however how can I firstly check the indetifier so I know in which format to decode it?

Comment: Is there any general way to take the buffer identifier ? I see that once I generate with flatc I get function like `*AccountRole_PacketIdentifier()` but that is only for that table. What if I have plenty and the server should use their identifiers to know what type exactly is that?

Answer (score 0):

As the [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030971/10871073) has pointed out, you can use `file_identifier` and a size prefix to determine the type and size of the incoming message.

```
namespace ns;

table Message {
  content: string;
}

file_identifier "MESG";

root_type Message;
```

Let's say you've defined this schema. To build the message with a size prefix and identifier, you'd need to use `builder.FinishSizePrefixed(message, ns::MessageIdentifier());`

```
flatbuffers::DetachedBuffer build_message(const std::string& content)
{
  flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
  auto message = ns::CreateMessage(builder, builder.CreateString(content));
  builder.FinishSizePrefixed(message, ns::MessageIdentifier());
  return builder.Release();
}
```

To send the message with asio:

```
auto message = build_message("Hello World");

asio::error_code ec;
asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(message.data(), message.size()), ec);
```

On the receiving end of your application, you can get the size of the message from the first 4 bytes of the data using `flatbuffers::GetSizePrefixedBufferLength`; and you can the type of the message with `flatbuffers::GetBufferIdentifier` after reading the entire message.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;

// read size
co_await asio::async_read(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(buffer, 4), asio::use_awaitable);

auto size = flatbuffers::GetSizePrefixedBufferLength(buffer.data());

// read message
co_await asio::async_read(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(buffer, size), asio::use_awaitable);

std::string type(
    flatbuffers::GetBufferIdentifier(buffer.data(), true),
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder::kFileIdentifierLength);
```

Once you know the type of the message, you can verify it and parse your message with a function generated by its schema:

```
// type == "MESG"
auto verifier = flatbuffers::Verifier(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
auto is_valid_message = ns::VerifySizePrefixedMessageBuffer(verifier);
auto message = ns::GetSizePrefixedMessage(buffer.data());

message->content(); // Hello World
```